# Timer in the background Swift

Tags: ios, swift, timer

I have the following code for my didEnterBackground function:

```
func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {

        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.

       Timer.after(5.seconds) {

        print ("5 seconds have past in the background")

        }
    }
```

The timer counts but the print doesn't go off until the application comes back into the foreground. I would like the print to go off 5 seconds after the application goes into the background.

Comment: You should show more information about what you have done and what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Anyone have any feedback on why this question was down voted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application does not execute code in background until and unless you have explicitly set it. However You cannot do whatever you want to do. Please go through [Apple Documents](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html) for more details.